# Getting junk values along with actual data while performing read operation in BLE scanner app

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on **nrf52832 in segger embedded studio**. Using **ble scanner app**, I am writing and reading some values. While reading the values, i am getting some junk data randomly. I'm writing data  to some arrays.

Consider  there are `A[2], B[4], C[45]`. To array  A and B, I'm writing complete data. so while reading them back, I'm getting the data. For `C[45],` I am not writing the complete data.

For example, its **size is 45**, i am only writing 5 bytes of data,so while reading them back,  i am getting **5 bytes of data along with 40 bytes of junk data**. 
My data is **12345**, Junk value is **12345!?M** .

What could be the issue?

```
static void on_write(ble_cus_t * p_cus, ble_evt_t const * p_ble_evt)
{
    ble_gatts_evt_write_t * p_evt_write = &p_ble_evt->evt.gatts_evt.params.write;

     Custom Value Characteristic Written to.
    if (p_evt_write->handle == p_cus->custom_value_handles.value_handle)
    {
        nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_4);
    }

    // Check if the Custom value CCCD is written to and that the value is the appropriate length, i.e 2 bytes.
    if ((p_evt_write->handle == p_cus->custom_value_handles.cccd_handle)
        && (p_evt_write->len == 2)
       )
    {

        NRF_LOG_INFO("on_write: len %d, p_evt_write->data[0]: %d, p_evt_write->data[1]: %d.",
                     p_evt_write->len,
                     p_evt_write->data[0],
                     p_evt_write->data[1]);

        // CCCD written, call application event handler
        if (p_cus->evt_handler != NULL)
        {
            ble_cus_evt_t evt;

            if (ble_srv_is_notification_enabled(p_evt_write->data))
            {
                evt.evt_type = BLE_CUS_EVT_NOTIFICATION_ENABLED;
            }
            else
            {
                evt.evt_type = BLE_CUS_EVT_NOTIFICATION_DISABLED;
            }
            // Call the application event handler.
            p_cus->evt_handler(p_cus, &evt);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check the line number 343 in utils.c code..the problem is there.

Comment: Ciould you please dump some sample code, how you actually write the array to the gatt service? It looks like there might be a length field which is not used corretly.

Comment: please find the sample code